# How to get Pivotal Cloud Cache idle timeout to reset on access

Tags: caching, cloud-foundry, gemfire

We are trying to set up cache expiration in Pivotal Cloud Cache, using Gemfire. We have set up our region in PCF:

```
Cluster-0 gfsh>describe region --name=/CartTest
 Type  |          Name           | Value
------ | ----------------------- | ---------
Region | data-policy             | PARTITION
       | entry-idle-time.timeout | 60
       | size                    | 0
       | statistics-enabled      | true
       | entry-idle-time.action  | DESTROY
```

When we create our `Cart` object, it is written to the cache (we can 
see it in the `size` entry above).

If we access our object from our code, it does not seem to be updating the access time for the entry. For instance:
    @11:00:00 - create entry
    @11:00:30 - access entry
    @11:01:00 - entry is gone

I would have expected the entry to still exist until 11:01:30 (I'm using ridiculously short timeouts just for testing). The idle time almost seems to be acting just like Time-To-Live. When we look at the `lastAccessTime` for the region using `gfsh`, it is not being updated.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Few things to verify.

- Can you please share code showing how you store data in PCC regions ?
- Is the region name correct ? Since you are using region *CarTest* in gfsh your **@Region** annotation (assuming you are using spring-data-gemfire on the client side) should also be using *CarTest* region name.

Easy way to put data using SDG (spring-data-gemfire) is via *Spring Data Repository* abstraction.

Please refer sample application [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/client/BootExampleApplication.java). Specifically domain class can be created like [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/client/model/Book.java) and repository can be created like [here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application/blob/master/boot-example/src/main/java/example/app/geode/cache/client/repo/BookRepository.java)

Comment: Thanks. I created a Gist here:
https://gist.github.com/dlwester-0510862/6b1310ea6ff1647b35a2b5f4e86566c8

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTION: The reason the `lastAccessedTime` was not being updated was because we were not getting the entry via the ID field, we were searching on two other fields in the object. When we took those two fields and created a composite key, and made it the `@Id` field, then the time was updated when we retrieved the object.

With partitioned Gemfire regions, any access to a secondary partition does not update the `lastAccessedTime` of the primary. So this won't do what we want, we'll need to add some code.